# How to swtich Protected Mode of IE in my own Explorer based on Microsoft Browser Activex control？

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, webbrowser-control, visual-c++, axwebbrowser

I made a simple browser based on Microsoft Browser Activex control,Any ways to switch protected mode in my own browser?

Comment: yes.or what else possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Unfortunately, there's no way to run your WebBrowser Control-hosting application in Protected Mode, as this is both unsupported and broken (because your application doesn't host the required broker objects).

Answer (score 1):

I take your "yes" as "switch on". I haven't done this myself, but I'd start my research with enabling the following [features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the process hosting `WebBrowser` control:

```
FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
FEATURE_ZONE_ELEVATION
FEATURE_WINDOW_RESTRICTIONS
FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN
FEATURE_RESTRICT_ACTIVEXINSTALL
FEATURE_VALIDATE_NAVIGATE_URL
FEATURE_PROTOCOL_LOCKDOWN
FEATURE_SAFE_BINDTOOBJECT
```

Let us know if you get there.

Comment: FWIW, none of those FCKs are related to Protected Mode (which is controlled by URLACTION_LOW_RIGHTS in IE, but that's meaningless outside of IE). But you're right to note that if his goal is to secure his client, then he should be looking at all of those FCKs and more.

Comment: @EricLaw, great info, appreciated. I think the OP also should make sure his app is UAC-compliant, which is a must in any case.

Comment: Thx but that was not what I wanted.